# identityserver client credential flow not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, identity

I am using identityserver 4 and i have 2 clients setup as per below:

```cs
     public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[]
            {
                
                 new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "bmprodevice",
                    ClientName = "BMPRO Client Credentials Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                  
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("blahblah".Sha256()) },
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "bellminderproapi", "scope2" },                    
                    Claims = new List<ClientClaim>()
                            {                         
                                new ClientClaim("BMClientTestClaim","BMClientTestClaim")
                            }
                },
                // interactive client using code flow + pkce
                         new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "interactive",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("blahblah2".Sha256()) },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44300/signin-oidc" },
                    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44300/signout-oidc",
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44300/signout-callback-oidc" },

                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "scope2" },
                       Claims = new List<ClientClaim>()
                            {
                                new ClientClaim("BMClientTestClaim","BMClientTestClaim")
                            }
                },
            };
    }
```

Here is my startup code:

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }
```

and

```cs
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

                // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
                options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
            })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
             
            services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {               
                options.AddPolicy("BMTestPolicy", policy =>
                {                                        
                    policy.RequireClaim("BMClientTestClaim");
                });
            });
            // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", options =>
                    {
                        options.ApiName = "bellminderproapi";              
                        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";               
              
                    });
```

Here is my config code :

```cs
// Copyright (c) Brock Allen & Dominick Baier. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See LICENSE in the project root for license information.


using IdentityServer4.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace identityserver4
{
    public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
                   new IdentityResource[]
                   {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),

                   };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new ApiScope[]
            {
                new ApiScope("scope1"),
                new ApiScope("scope2"),
                new ApiScope("bellminderproapi"),
                
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources => new[]
          {
              new ApiResource("bellminderproapi")
              {
                Scopes = new List<string> { "bellminderproapi" },
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("blahblahblah".Sha256())},
                UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"}
              }
            };

      
    }
}
```

If browse to a controller method (eg below:)

```
 [Authorize]
public class MikeTestController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        
        return Ok("Worked");
    }
}
```

then i get prompted with a login screen - i enter user name and password and  it works just fine - it returns worked.

HOWEVER

I am also trying to use the same api from client credentials flow with this code:

```
    public async Task testAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:5001");
        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
            return;
        }

        ClientCredentialsTokenRequest clientcred = new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
           
            GrantType = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
            ClientId = "bmprodevice",
            ClientSecret = "blahblah",   //note secret does match client in real code
            
            Scope = "bellminderproapi",
             
                            
        };
        clientcred.Properties.Add("device", "1234");
        // request token
        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(clientcred);

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);
        
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

        //var response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/test");
        //var response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/diagnostics");
        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/miketest");
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
        else
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine((content));
        }
    }
```

when i browse to the miketestcontoller above with the client credential flow code shown then it requests the bearer token and it is given one and identity server reports success in the log- but when i try and use the bearertoken to call the controller method (that has an authroize attribute) then instead of getting 'Worked' returned i get the login screen returned as the result.  Clearly it is redirecting to the login screen - but with client credential flow i have already provided the clientid and the clientsecret .....so shouldnt it already be authenticated and just return "worked"?

What am i doing wrong - i didnt think it should display the login screen with client credential flow.

below is the log from the app identity server app while trying to connect with the client credentials flow:

> 

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware
The request path /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks does not match a supported file type

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher
No candidates found for the request path '/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks'

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware
Request did not match any endpoints

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks matched to endpoint type Discovery

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint

[16:40:39 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint
Start key discovery request

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J8" completed keep alive response.

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics
Request finished in 18.2803ms 200 application/json; charset=UTF-8

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics
Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:5001/connect/token application/x-www-form-urlencoded 95

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware
POST requests are not supported

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher
No candidates found for the request path '/connect/token'

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware
Request did not match any endpoints

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Token, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint

[16:40:39 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
Start token request.

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
Start client validation

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser
Start parsing Basic Authentication secret

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.PostBodySecretParser
Start parsing for secret in post body

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J8", Request id "0HM8SREGO57J8:00000003": started reading request body.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J8", Request id "0HM8SREGO57J8:00000003": done reading request body.

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ISecretsListParser
Parser found secret: PostBodySecretParser

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ISecretsListParser
Secret id found: bmprodevice

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore
client configuration validation for client bmprodevice succeeded.

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ISecretsListValidator
Secret validator success: HashedSharedSecretValidator

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
Client validation success

[16:40:39 Information] IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService
{"ClientId": "bmprodevice", "AuthenticationMethod": "SharedSecret", "Category": "Authentication", "Name": "Client Authentication Success", "EventType": "Success", "Id": 1010, "Message": null, "ActivityId": "0HM8SREGO57J8:00000003", "TimeStamp": "2021-05-22T04:40:39.0000000Z", "ProcessId": 20808, "LocalIpAddress": "::1:5001", "RemoteIpAddress": "::1", "$type": "ClientAuthenticationSuccessEvent"}

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Start token request validation

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Start client credentials token request validation

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
bmprodevice credentials token request validation success

[16:40:39 Information] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Token request validation success, {"ClientId": "bmprodevice", "ClientName": "BMPRO Client Credentials Client", "GrantType": "client_credentials", "Scopes": "bellminderproapi", "AuthorizationCode": null, "RefreshToken": null, "UserName": null, "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "Tenant": null, "IdP": null, "Raw": {"grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "bellminderproapi", "client_id": "bmprodevice", "client_secret": "***REDACTED***"}, "$type": "TokenRequestValidationLog"}

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService
Getting claims for access token for client: bmprodevice

[16:40:39 Information] IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService
{"ClientId": "bmprodevice", "ClientName": "BMPRO Client Credentials Client", "RedirectUri": null, "Endpoint": "Token", "SubjectId": null, "Scopes": "bellminderproapi", "GrantType": "client_credentials", "Tokens": [{"TokenType": "access_token", "TokenValue": "****1qEA", "$type": "Token"}], "Category": "Token", "Name": "Token Issued Success", "EventType": "Success", "Id": 2000, "Message": null, "ActivityId": "0HM8SREGO57J8:00000003", "TimeStamp": "2021-05-22T04:40:39.0000000Z", "ProcessId": 20808, "LocalIpAddress": "::1:5001", "RemoteIpAddress": "::1", "$type": "TokenIssuedSuccessEvent"}

[16:40:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
Token request success.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J8" completed keep alive response.

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics
Request finished in 164.7192ms 200 application/json; charset=UTF-8

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J9" accepted.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J9" started.

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/miketest

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware
The request path /miketest does not match a supported file type

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher
1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/miketest'

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher
Endpoint 'IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.MikeTestController.Index (identityserver4test)' with route pattern '{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}' is valid for the request path '/miketest'

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware
Request matched endpoint 'IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.MikeTestController.Index (identityserver4test)'

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService
Authorization failed.

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J9" completed keep alive response.

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics
Request finished in 10.7394ms 302

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fmiketest

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware
The request path /Account/Login does not match a supported file type

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher
1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/Account/Login'

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher
Endpoint 'IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (identityserver4test)' with route pattern '{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}' is valid for the request path '/Account/Login'

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware
Request matched endpoint 'IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (identityserver4test)'

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware
Executing endpoint 'IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (identityserver4test)'

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker
Route matched with {action = "Login", controller = "Account"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] Login(System.String) on controller IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.AccountController (identityserver4test).

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker
Execution plan of authorization filters (in the following order): ["None"]

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker
Execution plan of resource filters (in the following order): ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter"]

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker
Execution plan of action filters (in the following order): ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ControllerActionFilter (Order: -2147483648)", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter (Order: -3000)", "IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.SecurityHeadersAttribute (Order: 0)"]

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker
Execution plan of exception filters (in the following order): ["None"]

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker
Execution plan of result filters (in the following order): ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter", "IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.SecurityHeadersAttribute (Order: 0)"]

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker
Executing controller factory for controller IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.AccountController (identityserver4test)

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker
Executed controller factory for controller IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.AccountController (identityserver4test)

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder
Attempting to bind parameter 'returnUrl' of type 'System.String' ...

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder
Attempting to bind parameter 'returnUrl' of type 'System.String' using the name 'returnUrl' in request data ...

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder
Done attempting to bind parameter 'returnUrl' of type 'System.String'.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder
Done attempting to bind parameter 'returnUrl' of type 'System.String'.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder
Attempting to validate the bound parameter 'returnUrl' of type 'System.String' ...

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder
Done attempting to validate the bound parameter 'returnUrl' of type 'System.String'.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine
View lookup cache miss for view 'Login' in controller 'Account'.

[16:40:39 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor
Executing ViewResult, running view Login.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor
The view path '/Views/Account/Login.cshtml' was found in 1.6874ms.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine
View lookup cache miss for view '_ValidationSummary' in controller 'Account'.

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.DefaultLinkGenerator
No endpoints found for address Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteValuesAddress

[16:40:39 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery
A new antiforgery cookie token was created.

[16:40:40 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine
View lookup cache miss for view '_Layout' in controller 'Account'.

[16:40:40 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine
View lookup cache miss for view '_Nav' in controller 'Account'.

[16:40:40 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor
Executed ViewResult - view Login executed in 47.4749ms.

[16:40:40 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker
Executed action IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (identityserver4test) in 140.9848ms

[16:40:40 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware
Executed endpoint 'IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (identityserver4test)'

[16:40:40 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J9" completed keep alive response.

[16:40:40 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics
Request finished in 162.0008ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8

[16:40:40 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J8" reset.

[16:40:40 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J8" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."

[16:40:40 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J8" disconnecting.

[16:40:40 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Connection id "0HM8SREGO57J8" stopped.

I have tried to give as much info as i can think may be required to work it out - if you need anything else then let me know - im new to identity server so someone with good knowledge will probably spot a few areas for improvement.

Comment: Not sure why my question was marked as doesn't show any research was done - I have tried about 20 different approaches including watching videos on lines and even starting from scratch with the identity server templates - I have tried for several weeks and am just getting myself more confused with every attempt.... I have certainly done a LOT of research to get to this point. I am hoping someone that understands the bigger picture on this than i do can offer some insight into what i have done wrong.

Comment: by default if you set up an app as a client, then the auth method will be `Cookies` so you need to modify the Authorize attribute as `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]`. I believe that to be the issue but i cannot be certain with the information provided

Comment: Ihusaan Ahmed - Thank you very much ...that solved the issue :)  - is there a way to make the Bearer the system wide default for AuthenticationSchemes so that i dont have to change all the authorize attributes?